# How to get the type of a variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, types

Does MATLAB have a function/operator that indicates the type of a variable (similar to the `typeof` operator in JavaScript)?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Use the [`class`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) function:

```
>> b = 2
b =
     2
>> a = 'Hi'
a =
Hi
>> class(b)
ans =
double
>> class(a)
ans =
char
```

Comment: for conditionals:
`if ( string(class(b)) == 'double' )
fprintf(1, 'b is double');
end`

Comment: Do note that you can overload the `class` method in a custom class to return any random string.

Answer (score 71):

The [class()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) function is the equivalent of `typeof()`.

You can also use [isa()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html) to check if a variable is of a particular type. If you want to be even more specific, you can use [ischar()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischar.html), [isfloat()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfloat.html), [iscell()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/iscell.html), etc.

Comment: Do note that in a custom class you can overload all of these methods to return anything you want.

Answer (score 45):

Another related function is [`whos`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html). It will list all sorts of information (dimensions, byte size, type) for the variables in a given workspace.

```
>> a = [0 0 7];
>> whos a
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1x3                24  double              

>> b = 'James Bond';
>> whos b
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  b         1x10               20  char
```

Comment: The [WHO](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/who.html) function does not list the size of variables. Because of that it is much faster if your workspace is crowded.

Answer (score 28):

Be careful when using the [isa](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html) function. This will be true if your object is of the specified type *or* one of its subclasses. You have to use [strcmp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) with the `class` function to test if the object is specifically that type and not a subclass.

Comment: Is this a response to [Dima's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578519/how-to-get-the-type-of-a-variable-in-matlab/578546#578546)?

Answer (score 5):

Since nobody mentioned it, MATLAB also has the [`metaclass`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/metaclass.html) function, which returns an object with various bits of information about the passed-in entity. These [`meta.class`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html) objects can be useful for tests of inheritance (via common comparison operators).

For example:

```
>> metaclass(magic(1))

ans = 

  class with properties:

                     Name: 'double'
              Description: ''
      DetailedDescription: ''
                   Hidden: 0
                   Sealed: 0
                 Abstract: 0
              Enumeration: 0
          ConstructOnLoad: 0
         HandleCompatible: 0
          InferiorClasses: {0×1 cell}
        ContainingPackage: [0×0 meta.package]
     RestrictsSubclassing: 0
             PropertyList: [0×1 meta.property]
               MethodList: [272×1 meta.method]
                EventList: [0×1 meta.event]
    EnumerationMemberList: [0×1 meta.EnumeratedValue]
           SuperclassList: [0×1 meta.class]

>> ?containers.Map <= ?handle

ans =

  logical

   1
```

We can see that `class(someObj)` is equivalent to the `Name` field of the result of `metaclass(someObj)`.

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB - Checking type of variables

> **class()** exactly works like Javascript's **typeof** operator.
>
> To get more details about variables you can use **whos** command or **whos()** function.

Here is the example code executed on **MATLAB R2017a**'s Command Window.

```
>> % Define a number
>> num = 67

num =

    67

>> % Get type of variable num
>> class(num)

ans =

    'double'

>> % Define character vector
>> myName = 'Rishikesh Agrawani'

myName =

    'Rishikesh Agrwani'

>> % Check type of myName
>> class(myName)

ans =

    'char'

>> % Define a cell array
>> cellArr = {'This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'big chance to learn ', 'MATLAB.'}; % Cell array
>> 
>> class(cellArr)

ans =

    'cell'

>> % Get more details including type
>> whos num
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  num       1x1                 8  double              

>> whos myName
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  myName      1x17               34  char               

>> whos cellArr
  Name         Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  cellArr      1x5               634  cell               

>> % Another way to use whos i.e using whos(char_vector)
>> whos('cellArr')
  Name         Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  cellArr      1x5               634  cell               

>> whos('num')
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  num       1x1                 8  double              

>> whos('myName')
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  myName      1x17               34  char               

>>
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the currently accepted answer.